# Need scripting help

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there somewhere that I can go to ask newbie questions on scripting languages, without getting my posting privileges removed? I asked a few questions on stackoverflow, but they 'didn't help others very much' and my posting privileges were removed. So is there some site that I can go to ask newbie questions, besides Yahoo Answers?

Comment: You might want to try the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).  If your questions are quite common issues then you also might want to try search for existing answers on [so].

Comment: I don't know the workings of the algorithm, however you don't appear to be 'deep' in the question ban area. A few up votes would probably lift it. The biggest problem I saw is that you don't often realize that we have no idea when it comes to the background of your problem, so perhaps be sure to add clear, concise context in the future. It helps if you read your question out loud, several times, refining it each time prior to posting (in addition to searching prior to asking).

Comment: Totally off topic but you asked for "some site" - well, before becoming regular here I roamed [aspfree forums](http://forums.aspfree.com/) you can always try your luck in there if it has relevant section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ask questions on scripting languages on stackoverflow. But...

- Stack Overflow does not replace a tutorial. So please ask specific questions, provide code samples and show what you have tried.
- Stack Overflow can not read your mind, so make the question clear and understandable.
- Stack Overflow doesn't like to answer the same question several times, so use the search function to find similar questions.
- Stack Overflow is no hire a programmer site, so we are glad to help, but we won't do your work for you.

If you are suspended from asking questions, you have probably violated these rules (or others). And if you like to continue the use of the site, you need to re-earn our trust. You can do this by editing your closed questions, and providing great answers to other questions. If you do this, there is a chance you will be able to ask questions again. (flag for a moderator or contact the team if you want to show that you have improved).